# check list elements include in other elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list as:

```
Lt = [((5,14),(8,14),(10,4)),((5,14),(8,14),(9,14)),((5,14),(8,14)),((5,14),(6,4),(8,14)),
       ((8,14),(9,14)),((8,14),(10,4))]
```

And i want get:

```
Lt = [((5,14),(8,14),(10,4)),((5,14),(8,14),(9,14)),((5,14),(6,4),(8,14))]
```

That mean is if Lt[i] include Lt[j], Lt[j] will be deleted.

And this is my ugly code:

```
def filter_clique(old_center):
# [(('X', 2), ('f', 6)), (('X', 2), ('O', 3)), (('X', 2), ('O', 3),('f', 6))]
# return: [(('X', 2), ('O', 3),('f', 6))]
# first: sorted list
old_center = sorted(old_center, key=lambda m: len(m), reverse=True)
rm_index = []
lth = len(old_center)
for i in range(lth-1):
    for j in range(i+1, lth):
        if set(old_center[j]).issubset(set(old_center[i])):
            rm_index.append(j)
if len(rm_index):
    old_center = np.delete(old_center, rm_index).tolist()
    return old_center
else:
    return old_center
```

If my list is lager, this process is becoming very expensive.

Which way is the fastest to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: You mean to remove tuples that are subsets of other tuples in the list?

Comment: Please post what you already tried to achieve this and where you are struggling.

Comment: yes, i want to remove an element if it is subset of other element. Do you have any idea?

Comment: and this is my ugly code:

Comment: Please change coding standard this is not clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: Is the ordering important?

Comment: the ordering is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Here the new try :

```
sets = list(map(set, Lt))
new_list = [l for l,s in zip(Lt, sets) if not any(s < other for other in sets)]
print(new_list)

# [(5, 14, 8, 14, 10, 4), (5, 14, 6, 4, 8, 14), (5, 14, 8, 14, 9, 14)]
```

Comment: i have already tried your code, but it is very slow. Have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Hatran try the new method added.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
Lt = [(5,14,8,14,10,4),(5,14,8,14,9,14),(5,14,8,14),(5,14,6,4,8,14),(8,14,9,14),(8,14,10,4)]
Lt = sorted(set(Lt), key=lambda m: len(m), reverse=True)
res = []
while Lt:
    val = Lt.pop()
    if not any(set(val).issubset(set(i)) for i in Lt):
        res.append(val)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[(5, 14, 8, 14, 10, 4), (5, 14, 8, 14, 9, 14), (5, 14, 6, 4, 8, 14)]
```